# How to build Visual Studio Setup projects (.vdproj) with TFS 2010 Build ?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, installation

We have a solution that contains VS (2013) setup projects. Apparently MSBuild does not support building such projects so we have to run the build manually through dev machines. 
I saw the following link that shows a workaround:

http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/building-vs-2015-setup-projects-in-team-build#comments

BUT we would like NOT to install VS on our build machine.

Is there a way to workaround this problem?
What is the best way to build setup projects in a build machine?
Thanks

Comment: A build machine should be almost identical to a developer workstation. If your developer workstations have Visual Studio, your build machines should as well. Copies of Visual Studio installed on build machines typically don't count against your licenses.

Answer (score 0):

Team Build 2010 invokes MSBuild to build project on build agent machine by default. If one project don’t support MSBuild to build it, we need provide a compiler which can build this project, and this compiler support run the command line to invoke it, so we can add the **InvokeProcess** activity(execute the command line) to invoke that compiler to build this project in build process template.

If VS is the compiler you build this setup project, then it's needed to be installed on your build machine.

Building Visual Studio Setup Projects with TFS 2010 Team Build:
http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/05/building-visual-studio-setup-projects-with-tfs-2010-team-build/