# Build vdproj file with VS 2013 and TFS 2013 - getting a build error - An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '8000000A'

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to build vdproj (VS setup project files) files on a build machine.
* VS 2013 installed on the build machine with Visual Studio Setup projects extension installed
* TFS 2013

The build is done by running devenv.com (using InvokeProcess activity) and we can see that it is starting properly but then we get the following error:
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'

I googled for this answer and all the solutions I saw did not help...
* adding the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_Config\MSBuild\EnableOutOfProcBuild DWORD value to 0
* restart...

Would really appreciate your help here....

Comment: all the following links do not provide an answer to this question:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719295/how-to-build-visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-with-tfs-2010-build?noredirect=1#comment62916417_37719295;   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648428/an-error-occurred-while-validating-hresult-8000000a  ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32913420/visual-studio-2013-and-tfs-build-2015-devenv-exe-unable-to-produce-msi-file/32934063#32934063

Comment: Here are the log lines:     6/16/2016 3:56:24 PM  ------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'XXXMsInstaller' ------
6/16/2016 3:56:24 PM  ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
6/16/2016 3:56:24 PM  ------ Pre-build validation for project 'XXXMsInstaller' completed ------
6/16/2016 3:56:24 PM  6>------ Rebuild All started: Project: XXXMsInstaller, Configuration: Debug ------
6/16/2016 3:56:24 PM  ========== Rebuild All: 5 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Did you modify the registry key on your build agent machine? Are you able to build the project with devenv.exe locally on build agent machine?

Comment: Even when running locally on the build machine, I get that build error.

Comment: And yes, I did change the registry key on the build machine

Comment: Before using TFS build, you have to make sure the project can be built locally. Do you have another build machine to test your project?

Comment: Yes I have . I tried running the same command line on my dev machine.

Comment: I even created a new solution with 2 projects, one with a dll and one with a setup project (that installs that dll). Running the following command line generates the same error:

Comment: >"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "c:\Users\dafna\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HelloWorld\HelloWorld.sln"  /Project "HelloWorldSetup"  /Build

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Version 12.0.40629.0.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'HelloWorldSetup' ------
ERROR: An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '8000000A'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'HelloWorldSetup' completed ------
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorldSetup, Configuration: Debug ------
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: How about use devenv.exe instead of devenv.com?

Comment: My intention is to build it in the build machine, how can I do that using devenv.exe....?    I did a very simple and basic thing of creating a solution with two projects (dll and setup project) and this still doesn't compile by devenv.com in a command line ... how can that be...?

Comment: Why can't use devenv.exe?  Adding InvokeProcess activity to invoke devenv.exe compiler.

Comment: I first need to understand why it fails on a simple development machine. Once it compiles successfully, I know how to put this as a activity in the TFS

Comment: I'm not sure why as I'm not familiar with setup project. You may try to repair your VS and the extension, or set up another build agent machine and run this project on it to see whether you would reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks but this is a known issue for setup projects... But all the workarounds i saw online do not work for me. The solution is being built perfectly inside VS but is i want to build it from a command line using devenv.com (msbuild does not build setup projects), it fails with a strange error

Comment: Yes, I also saw the workarounds online, but weird that it didn't work for you. So I suggest you try on another machine to see whether you would get the same error. Maybe there is some incorrect setting on your build machine.

Comment: It failed on 3 different machines....

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to solve this problem. Apparently this is a known issue with some workarounds that sometime work. For me they didn't and there was simply no way in compiling my vdproj with msbuild. 
What we did is moved our setup to be a wix project.... this msbuild supports.